# ggplot maps - unwanted horizontal lines when using coord_map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I've problem with projecting properly map of Europe when I use `coord_map` in `ggplot` package. The code below gives me a weird and unwanted horizontal lines in random places. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

I don't want to use `coord_quickmap` nor `coord_cartesian` because I want to preserve straight lines of countries.

```
library(ggplot2)

map.world <- map_data("world")

ggplot(map.world, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill =  "#B3B1B5", color = "#D9D8DA",size = 0.4) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), text = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-27,36), ylim = c(34,67))
```

[image]

Comment: I get the same thing. Without the last bit - `coord_map`, the whole world plots nicely.

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3530 (closed, no fix)

Comment: Seems to work fine with `coord_quickmap(...)` instead.

Comment: @markhogue yes, without `coord_map` it plots the whole world nicely, but I want to zoom the map only to European countries.

Comment: @r2evans yes, it works with `coord_quickmap` but I think it distorts some countries like Spain and Finland

Comment: There seems to be an offset from longitude ~63 to ~70. But I found that if the max latitude is kept >= 50, it's okay.

Comment: Update: I get a really nice map with `coord_map(xlim = c(-27.5,36.5), ylim = c(33.5,63))` (close to your original values) but ONLY if the world map is regenerated first. The `map.world` is somehow changed when it's plotted.

Comment: @markhogue yes, this seems to work :) Thank you! BTW what do you mean by regenerated?

Comment: If you plot without doing the ‘map.world’ assignment, there is residual impact on the map. Surprising

Comment: @markhogue, that is *really interesting* to me. What business does `ggplot2` have in changing the underlying data? I confirmed it with `tracemem(map.world)`, and it is being changed in the original `ggplot(...)`, regardless of `coord_map` or `coord_quickmap`. I'm not certain yet if that's really concerning or just the cost of doing business ...

Comment: (It also changes "basic data", I reproduced that behavior with `mtcars`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to work around your problem:

**The straightforward way**

This way just needs a little tweaking of your code (note that I use magrittr's forward [pipes](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/)):

```
library(maps)
library(magrittr)
library(maptools)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

europe <-  maps::map("world", fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE) %>%
                 maptools::pruneMap(xlim = c(-27,36), ylim = c(34,67))

ggplot(data= broom::tidy(europe)) + 
  geom_polygon(mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill =  "#B3B1B5", color = "#D9D8DA",size = 0.4) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map()
```

**The "owin/extent" approach**

Another way to work around your problem can be done by using [owin](https://rdrr.io/cran/spatstat/man/owin.html) objects. This kind of objects will allow you to create a spatial window. Then you can represent only the intersection of such window over the world map.

Using this approach your code will be something as follows (also using magrittr's forward [pipes](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/) and setting up a general [CRS](https://epsg.io/4326))

```
library(maps)
library(magrittr)
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

#Defining a general EPSG so there won't be any superposition problems
epsg <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

#Using the original maps package, then converting map into SpatialPolygons object
map.world <- maps::map("world", fill=TRUE) %$% 
  maptools::map2SpatialPolygons(., IDs=names,proj4string=CRS(epsg))

#In order to keep the names of the countries we create the following data.frame
country.labs <- sapply(slot(map.world, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID")) %>% 
  data.frame( ID=1:length(map.world), name=., row.names = .) 

#We convert object map.world into a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object
map.world.SPDF <- sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(map.world, country.labs) 

#Creating owin object using your zooming coordinates
#This step always requires to load packages 'spatstat' and 'maptools'
zoom <- as(spatstat::as.owin(c(-27,36,34,67)), "SpatialPolygons") 
raster::projection(zoom)=epsg

#Storing intersection between 'zoom' and 'world.map'
europe <- raster::intersect(map.world.SPDF, zoom)

#*country names of object europe can be accessed via europe@data

#Representing object 'europe' using broom::tidy to create a data.frame object
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = broom::tidy(europe, region="name"), 
               mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill =  "#B3B1B5", color = "#D9D8DA",size = 0.4) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map()

#*country names after tidying 'europe' this way are in a new column called 'id'
```

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to use

```
zoom <- as(raster::extent(c(-27,36,34,67)), "SpatialPolygons")
```

To create an **extent** object instead of an **owin** object (The result here is going to be the same)

The result obtained with any method is displayed below

[image]

In case you need to do different zooms you can easily wrap any of the alternatives up in a function.

I hope it helps

**BONUS BALL:** It might be interesting for you to check out the [tmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html) package

Comment: thank you, you're life saver! Just one more thing - what can I do to preserve country names in the object `tidy(europe)`?

Comment: I'll edit my answer so the object _europe_ include the names of the countries

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: I'm adding a much more straightforward way to accomplish what you wanted thanks to the function `maptools::pruneMap` :)

Comment: Nicely thorough answer!

Comment: @Pawliczek you could consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers